# Wordpress - How to make thumbnail a link to post?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, thumbnails

I have some problem. I use Wordpress theme - [Intergalatic](https://intergalacticdemo.wordpress.com/). But in homepage, the large background of post do not take us to the post. The background must be clickable and move us to the post. How to do it?

This is code of thumbnail.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'intergalactic-large' ); ?>
            <div class="entry-background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>)"></div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: try wp_get_attachment_url and not wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in the loop, and by the looks of it you are, then you'll need to change div to anchor

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'intergalactic-large' ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" class="entry-background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>)"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

And probably change the anchor to `display:inline-background;` and possibly add the height of the image to the styling like:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'intergalactic-large' ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" class="entry-background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>); height:<?php echo esc_attr($thumbnail[2]);?> px"></a>
<?php } ?>
```